# "Could lie down"/" Could lay down"

Tags: word-choice

"I wish I could just sit here and lay down beside you forever."

Shouldn’t it be "lie down" instead of "lay down" here?  As we know that the verb following " could" should be of base form. But, here "lay down" is past form of "lie down".

Besides, if we consider "lay down" in present tense it means " laying egg" or "laying something"-  meaning not consistent with the context.

I  want to if the sentence is correct.

Comment: Who said that it was laydown? You should  show a specific example

Comment: I found it on a practice website. It says "I wish I could just sit here and lay down beside you forever." is okay.

Comment: As you say, it is not OK.